How to catch RuntimeError and prevent it from propagating my UI
I am using a library to translate my entire site to any language
I'm using two JavaScript libraries Float.js and lang.js
It works well until I switch tabs and I get runtime errors and I cant determine where they're coming from in the library
Using the I18N library is very tedious and this is much cleaner and easier. The issue I'm having is the runtime error when change I focus on the page.
This is the component where I want the button to render on all my layouts and translate every page in the routes
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AuthHeader from "./header/AuthHeader";
import Sidebar from "./sidebar/Sidebar";
import ErrorBoundary from "../ErrorBoundary";

const AuthLayout = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const [showSidebar, setSidebar] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadScript = (id, src) => {
      if (document.getElementById(id)) return; // Prevent reloading if script already exists

      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = src;
      script.id = id;
      script.defer = true;
      script.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      script.addEventListener("error", (e) => {
        console.error(`Error loading ${src}:`, e);
      });

      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };

    loadScript("customScript", `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/float.js`);
    loadScript("langScript", `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/lang.js`);

    return () => {
      // Optional cleanup, if required
      const customScript = document.getElementById("customScript");
      const langScript = document.getElementById("langScript");
      if (customScript) customScript.remove();
      if (langScript) langScript.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleVisibilityChange = () => {
      if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
        console.log("Tab is active again. Re-checking scripts...");
        // Additional handling if needed, like re-attaching event listeners
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);

    return () => document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);
  }, []);

  window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
    console.error("Global error caught:", { message, source, lineno, colno, error });
    return true;
  };

  window.onunhandledrejection = (event) => {
    console.error("Unhandled promise rejection:", event.reason);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <div className="gtranslate_wrapper"></div>
      <div className="d-flex" style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        {showSidebar && (
          <Sidebar showSidebar={showSidebar} setSidebar={setSidebar} />
        )}
        <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          <AuthHeader showSidebar={showSidebar} setSidebar={setSidebar} />
          <div style={{ height: "91vh", overflow: "auto" }} {...props}>
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};

export default AuthLayout;

I have an error boundary component that's supposed to catch and handle any runtime error and prevent them from propagating my UI. But it doesn't seem to get it done.
Attached below is the errorBoundary component
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state to display fallback UI on error
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    console.error("Error caught by ErrorBoundary:", error, info);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h2>Something went wrong. Please try reloading the page.</h2>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;

**Attached below is the image of the error i get **

